# SSL on Apache HTTP Server

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, ssl-certificate, private-key

I have 2 crt files for Apache server:

- 1_root_bundle.crt
- 2_my_domain_name.com.crt

And other bundle:

- 1_Intermediate.crt
- 2_my_domain_name.com.crt
- root.crt

I have modified

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

And tried various combinations of above mentioned files but after Apache2 service restart SSL does not work, browser shows "Connection is not secure":

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/1_Intermediate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/2_my_domain_name.com.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/root.crt
```

How to make SSL on Apache server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is missing the key file with your certificate private key. Usually it has the  `.key`  extension like `2_my_domain_name.com.key` and the file content starts with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`

You configuration should looks like this

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/2_my_domain_name.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/2_my_domain_name.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/1_root_bundle.crt
```

The SSLCertificateChainFile points to a all-in-one file where you can assemble the certificates of Certification Authorities (CA) which form the certificate chain of the server certificate.

So ensure that `1_root_bundle.crt` contains `1_Intermediate.crt` content and is in PEM format (base64 with `--- BEGIN CERTIFICATE --- ----END CERTIFICATE---` headers)

If you use apache >= 2.4.8 you could also concatenate all certificates in the file pointed at `SSLCertificateFile`

> SSLCertificateChainFile became obsolete with version 2.4.8, when SSLCertificateFile was extended to also load intermediate CA certificates from the server certificate file.

Comment: How to get .key file?

Comment: You are the one who (should) create the private key. You can generate it with openssl. Then you can create a csr (certificate signing request) file from the key. You have to send that to to the Certificate authority, they will send back your signed certificate matched to your key, and the intermediate certificate(s).

Answer (score 1):

1) Install Apache HTTP Server, mod_ssl

2) Configure httpd

Remember to disable SSLv2 and SSLv3, because they are vulnerable.

```
  # Toggle on the SSL/TLS Protocol Engine
  SSLEngine On
  # The signed certificate of the server
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/myserver/myserver.crt
  # The private key of the server
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/myserver/myserver.key
  # The intermediate_certificate of the server
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/myserver/tls-ca-chain.pem

  # Accept only strong encryption
  SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite           HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
  SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
```

3) Check the permissions on the certificate files.

**UPD**:
How to create a key and certificate signing request in one step:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout myserver.key -out myserver.csr
```

Next you have to send this csr file to one of the certificate authorities. They will send back your signed certificate, and the intermediate certificate(s).

You can also create a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bundle file with SSLCertificateChainFile.

```
SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/tad.com/tad.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/tad.com/tad.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ubuntu/tad.com/intermediate_bundle.crt
SSLCACertificateFile /home/ubuntu/zup.today/intermediate_bundle.crt
```

OR

If you are using bundle so it will work without  SSLCertificateChainFile file.

```
SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/tad.com/tad.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/tad.com/tad.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /home/ubuntu/zup.today/intermediate_bundle.crt
```