# Multiple Virtual host with Port 443 pointing to wrong directory

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, virtualhost, digital-ocean

I have created two virtual host files on ubuntu apache2

```
   www.example1.com.conf 
   www.example2.com.conf
```

which is working fine  with port 80. without https.

I have added following code for 443

```
VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin info@example1
    ServerName  example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example1.com/
    #SSLEngine on
    #SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example1.crt
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example1.key
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin info@example2
    ServerName  example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example2.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when i am opening https://www.example2.com/, i am seeing content of example1.com.

but if i do http://www.example2.com/ then content is ok.

Can you please suggest what will be the issue ?

Comment: If you want to use SSL then make sure that VirtualHost has a Certificate and key file. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939806/ssl-on-apache-http-server

Comment: Is that required. Can't i use without key file. it may give server errror but why it is pointing to wrong directory

Comment: its not working btw...

Comment: It should give the error if you use https VirtualHost without key  and Certificate. Also note that in NameBased VirtualHost if a request is received that does not match one of the specified ServerName directives, it will be served by the first <VirtualHost> defined in the configuration files as the default.

Comment: k then why exaple2.com with https is showing content of example1.com